# Android - Formatting Bitmap to match instagram size

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Myapp calls the camera app, takes a picture, sends the pic path back to Myapp to be displayed in an ImageView and to then be shared to Instagram. I want the displayed bitmap to be of the same dimensions as what Instagram uses so no unexpected cropping will happen when going from Myapp to Instagram.

Here's what I've tried so far when returning from the camera:

(note: `INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_W == INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_H == 1080`)

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.outHeight = INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_H;
bmOptions.outWidth = INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_W;
bmOptions.inMutable = true;
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_H, INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_W, false);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

This distorts the image to fit the square format; not optimal

```
 BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 bmOptions.outHeight = INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_H;
 bmOptions.outWidth = INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_W;
 bmOptions.inMutable = true;
 Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);
 int baseX = (photo.getWidth() - INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_W)/2;
 int baseY = (photo.getHeight() - INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_H)/2;
 Bitmap photoResized = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo,baseX,baseY,INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_W,INSTAGRAM_FORMAT_H);
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 photoResized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

This crops too much off what the user sees thru the camera app, it is also bigger than the Instagram size which results in additional cropping when going to Instagram; not optimal

I was digging thru BitmapFactory.Options and possible parameters for Bitmap.createBitmap but I'm pretty lost in terms of what best practice is for when/where the formatting occurs, how to deal with variable pixel density of the screen (if needed) and variable camera definition (if applicable).

I could use a helping hand folks. Thanks